# Is there a functional way to traverse a stream accumulating and filtering based in last processed items?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I received a ordered list of transaction requests done in a period by all customers that have same credit-limit.
My goal is to generate a list of all transactions that was madden after the credit-limit have been passed.

In order to do that I need to take the amount of each transaction and withdraw from the the customer's credit-limit.

I'm learning and trying to resolve that using java11 streams, but I could not find a way to do in a single traversing and in a functional way.

Initially, I grouped the transactions by customer:

```
Map<Customer, List<Transaction>> result = transactions.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getCustomer));
```

But then I traversed the result, accumulating the transaction amounts and adding the transaction to the desired list when its amount is bigger than the limit:

```
List<String> toAnalise = new ArrayList<>();
result.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
    int total = 0;
    for (Transaction transaction : entry.getValue()) {
      if ((total + transaction.amount) <= creditLimit ){
            total += transaction.amount;
        } else {
          toAnalise.add(transaction.transactionId);
        }               
    }
});
```

I have a feeling that this could be improved :)

---

I've improved my solution... seems better :)

Now I'm returning the list of the transaction directly:

```
List<String> toBeAnalised = transactions.stream()
        .map(t -> new Transaction(t, creditLimit))
        .collect(groupingBy(Transaction::getConsumer,
                collectingAndThen(toCollection(TreeSet::new),
                TransactionsVersion2::validateTransactions)))
        .values().stream().flatMap(List<String>::stream)
        .collect(toList());
```

Also I moved the transaction validation to its own method allowing it to be called from the stream processing:

```
private static List<String> validateTransactions(Set<Transaction> transactions) {
    int total = 0;
    List<String> rejected = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
        if ((total + transaction.amount) <= transaction.consumer.limit)
        {
            total += transaction.amount;
        } else {
            rejected.add(transaction.transactionId);
        }
    }
    return rejected;
}
```

Could it be improved yet ?

Comment: *accumulating the transaction amounts and and adding the transaction to the desired list when its amount is bigger than the limit*....you seem to be looking for something like `takeWhile`

Answer (score 1):

using `takeWhile` something like :

```
List<String> toAnalise = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<Transaction> value : result.values()) {
    AtomicInteger total = new AtomicInteger(0);
    toAnalise.addAll(value.stream()
            .takeWhile(a -> total.addAndGet(a.amount) <= creditLimit)
            .map(t -> t.transactionId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: assumption: have considered the amount as an Integer for simplicity

Comment: The original loop collects those transactions *not* fitting into the limit. Further, it does not stop on the first non-fitting transaction. And your predicate `a -> total.addAndGet(a.amount) <= creditLimit` will modify the `total` even when not accepting the transaction. Generally, side effects in predicates are problematic and rely on assumptions about the implementation.

Comment: thanks @Naman, but Holger is right. 

The takeWhile() predicate will sum even if the transaction is not aimed to be accepted. Also it can prevent other transactions to be processed and accepted since it is short-circuit.

Comment: @user_3380739 Seems like also from the comments that I've got the reverse of the logic expected in the question. But would need to spend some time to understand what exactly is the requirement in that case.